# How can I reset the service battery warning?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I learned from one of my other questions that the "Service Battery" warning will limit your CPU power and slow your computer down - this is a problem I've been having with my MacBook Pro.

I have 906 cycles on it but I'm still getting good life and unfortunately, I don't have time to go to get my battery replaced ATM since it's the middle of exam season for me.

Resetting the SMC gets me going for a while with full CPU speed, but then it slows down again.

How can I disable this warning and get my computer back for the next week?

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is you can not reset the cycle counter, it is a part of battery circuit. Your battery is at its end of life (EOL).

### Temperature

How to keep battery running just a bit longer, **keep it cold.**

Do not have your laptop on your lap even if the name says so.

Go to your fridge and get one of those jelly-packs and put it under the laptop.

### Energy Saving

Quit or disable any applications you are not actively using.

Dim the screen as much you can.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thin you can reset the warning, but just in case you missed it, check out my reply to your other post about the original problem you're trying to solve.

[Constant SMC resets required](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128570/constant-smc-resets-required)